# Generating a sphere manually

Tags: opengl, geometry, lwjgl

In opengl (lwjgl for java), using glu.Sphere.Sphere() can make it very easy to generate a sphere but after some tens of spheres with 32x32 resolution, it becomes very slow. Now Im thinking of using buffers to send vertices+colors+normals+indices only once and change them using opencl.

**Question:** If I take origin as (0,0,0) as center of sphere, can I choose a normal just equal to its vertex?

Example: North pole of sphere is the vertex=(0,1,0)  so can its surface-normal be (0,1,0) again? Can we do same thing for all vertices? What about element array order if we can make it optimized? Guessing a triangle vertex can be used by many neighbour triangles. Im a begineer so I need some pointer to useage of efficient drawElementArray function and index array generation.

Note: Im keeping my cpu at 1400MHz so it cant handle much computing on host side and opengl does not accept multi-threaded drawing of spheres.

Following Valentin's suggestion, I opened inside of glu and found this to be drawing element by element. Will use this for buffer generation.

```
if (this.drawStyle == 100010)
        {
          GL11.glBegin(0);
          if (normals)
            GL11.glNormal3f(0.0F, 0.0F, nsign);
          GL11.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, radius);
          if (normals)
            GL11.glNormal3f(0.0F, 0.0F, -nsign);
          GL11.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, -radius);

          for (int i = 1; i < stacks - 1; i++) {
            float rho = i * drho;
            for (int j = 0; j < slices; j++) {
              float theta = j * dtheta;
              float x = cos(theta) * sin(rho);
              float y = sin(theta) * sin(rho);
              float z = cos(rho);
              if (normals)
                GL11.glNormal3f(x * nsign, y * nsign, z * nsign);
              GL11.glVertex3f(x * radius, y * radius, z * radius);
            }
          }
          GL11.glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is getting slower and slower, is because the `GLU` geometry meshes rendered using `GLU` uses immediate mode for rendering.

You could download a `Java Decompiler` and decompile `lwjgl_util.jar`, then you just follow the package paths to `glu.Sphere.Sphere()` and then you can lookup the `draw()` method. Take a look and see how the code works, and then basically create you own method but instead of using `glVertex`, etc methods. Just add the values to a `FloatBuffer`, and then create a `VBO` of the Sphere.

[Here is a free Java Decompiler!](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It draws element by element. Will use that, thank you. Do you have a hint for element indices for optimization?

Comment: Well using Array Elements, that really depends on the model and its complexity. Though for a simple sphere, I would just use a regular VBO and store everything.

Comment: So, as long as a sphere fits in a compute-unit's local memory, it is no problem? 32x32 means 1k vertices mean 3k coordinates and 3k colours mean 12kB for coordinates and some other for colours. I dont know how to draw without indices. drawArray() or drawVertexArray()?

Comment: You need to use the `glDrawArrays()` method. For rendering `VBOs`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then I will group these spheres as a single vbo to draw with a single call. I wish they dont weld into single shape :( glDrawArrays() uses a parallel-way to draw right? Not serially I mean.

Comment: Well you can just create a new VBO for each Sphere, and if you have 2 spheres with the same size, etc. then those 2 spheres can share the same VBO.

Comment: You mean, I can use only one VBO and a displacement array for other spheres? They are same size and same orientation(they are simple spheres)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "displacement array" I've never heard of such a thing in OpenGL.

Comment: All spheres will have same size and resolution but their locations are different and maybe colors too. You said, same sized spheres use same vbo but I need them to be different positions. When I have 1000 spheres, do they use only first vbo? I need to call drawing command only once for whole world.

Comment: Well then for doing that really basically, you would ofc call the `glDrawArrays()` for each sphere. Then before you call `glDrawArrays()` you would just translate and rotation, everything how you please.

Comment: I mean how can I batch 10000 spheres into a single buffer object? Do I need to add some spaces(zeroes or something between different objects)

Comment: You might wanna look into this instead! http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing